# What is 'parsecs per cubic centimeters' in a radio source's dispersion measure?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, units, dimensional-analysis

The units of 'parsecs per cubic centimeter' is really hurting my brain...

Could someone please explain this weird astronomical unit?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the dispersion is interaction with charges.  Because of the mass difference, it turns out that electrons are the main cause and we can almost ignore protons and other nuclei.

Therefore the density of electrons in the intervening space drives the dispersion as the radiation travels through space.

When quoted in parsecs per cubic centimeter, and knowing the electron density per cubic centimeter, you can therefore directly infer distance in parsecs.

$$D = \frac{DM}{n_e}$$

Comment: Why did someone downvote your answer, BowlOfRed?  I just upvoted it back to zero...  I hope your answer is accurate...

Comment: No idea.  Here's another reference with similar information.  https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/P/Pulsar+Dispersion+Measure